How is multiplicative disjunction understood in a logic programming language?
I'm considering employing linear logic (or more specifically, MALL) as the typesystem for my programming language. Recall that linear logic is defined with four binary connectives: Multiplicative conjunction $\otimes$, additive disjunction $\oplus$, additive conjunction $\&$, and multiplicative disjunction $⅋$.
$\otimes$ is easy. The type $P \otimes Q$ consists of pairs of a value typed $P$ and a value typed $Q$. Though, this interpretation has few consequences:

$P \otimes Q$ cannot be implicitly casted into $Q \otimes P$. For consider the type $\mathrm{Int} \otimes \mathrm{Int}$. After shuffling the two values involved, we wouldn't be able to know which is which now.

The identity element $1$ of $\otimes$ can be safely interpreted as the empty tuple. Furthermore, $1$ can be treated to have zero size in the memory. As a consequence, $P \otimes 1$ (and $1 \otimes P$ also) can be implicitly casted into $P$, and vice versa.


$\oplus$ is also easy; it is the union of $P$ and $Q$, using one of the involved types itself as the tag.

By employing C-esque union, unlike multiplicative conjunction, $P \oplus Q$ can be implicitly casted into $Q \oplus P$.

$P$ (and $Q$ also) can be implicitly casted into $P \oplus Q$. The converse doesn't hold.

$P \oplus P$ can be implicitly casted into $P$.

The identity element $0$ of $\oplus$ is the uninhabited type. $0$ can be implicitly casted into an arbitrary type, and every successful production of a value in $0$ shall result in panicking.


$\&$ is quite harder to be understood. The key feature is that, unlike $P \otimes Q$, taking $P$ from $P \& Q$ results in dropping the $Q$, and taking $Q$ from $P \& Q$ results in dropping the $P$. So $P \& Q$ should not be understood as having a distinctive memory model, but should be understood as letting the interpreter decide which type to express.

$P \& Q$ can be implicitly casted into $Q \& P$.

$P \& Q$ can be implicitly casted into $P$, or into $Q$. The interpreter shall decide which one it shall cast into, or lazily leave it undecided when possible.

$P$ can be implicitly casted into $P \& P$.

The identity element $\top$ of $\&$ can be understood as a deallocated storage; every type can be implicitly casted into $\top$, which shall destroy the involved value.


But what about $⅋$? As far as I've understood, the key feature is that, dropping $P$ from $P ⅋ Q$ shall result in taking $Q$, and dropping $Q$ from $P ⅋ Q$ shall result in taking $P$. How should its semantics be understood in the perspective of a logic programming language?

Here's are interesting question & answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50340/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-par-operator-in-linear-logic

Post-comment: The cast to $\top$ doesn't destroy anything; rather, it leaves the value intact. It only conceals the type.

Multiplicative conjunction is conjunction in the usual logic-programming sense. If the goal is $A \otimes B$ and the context is $C$, the judgement is $C \vdash A \otimes B$, and you can decompose this into proving $C_1 \vdash A$ and then $C_2 \vdash B$, where $C \cong C_1, C_2$.
To avoid the nondeterminism of choosing how to partition the resources in $C$, it’s a typical optimisation in linear logic programming to supply all of $C$ when trying to produce $A$, and consider whatever was consumed to be $C_1$; then the remainder $C_2$ is passed along to try to produce $B$.
Additive disjunction is choice in the usual sense. To prove $C \vdash A \oplus B$, you can try to prove $C \vdash A$, then if that fails (effectively producing 0), backtrack and try to prove $C \vdash B$.
Additive conjunction is dual to additive disjunction, so a goal of $A \mathbin{\&} B$ is equivalent to having $A^\bot \oplus B^\bot$ in the context. This is also a search, but instead of checking multiple ways to satisfy one goal, it’s checking multiple goals against one context.
You can think of a program in LLP as a duplicable additive conjunction of all the rules: head1 :- body1. … headN :- bodyN. = $!((B_1 \multimap H_1) \mathbin{\&} \ldots \mathbin{\&} (B_n \multimap H_n))$. In other words: any number of times, try to apply one of the rules by matching its head against the current goals, and adding its body as a subgoal.
When you have a multiplicative disjunction $A \mathbin{⅋} B$ as a goal, this is a “fork” where you can start trying to satisfy multiple goals simultaneously. The goals aren’t contradictory, but they are mutually incompatible in the sense that, if you focus on one of them to prove, you still have the obligation to deal with the other one.
One interpretation of the state $C \vdash A \mathbin{⅋} B$ is as a choice, $(C \otimes B^\bot \multimap A) \mathbin{\&} (C \otimes A^\bot \multimap B)$, based on commutativity of $⅋$. You would try to prove $A$ under the assumption that it can produce $B$ somehow to refute the $B^\bot$, and if that fails, you’d try it the other way around.
Another interpretation is to spawn two parallel tasks, where each may produce a result or join the other by sending a message to it and quitting—returning $\bot$, which is the unit of $⅋$. So an implication $A \multimap B$ is a parallel pair $A^\bot \mathbin{⅋} B$ where maybe the $A^\bot$ side consumes an input and sends it to the $B$ task to compute a result, or maybe the $B$ task produces a thunk that, when forced, awaits input from the $A$ task, but the $B$ can never be used to compute the $A$ because the tasks are disjoint.
A few good places to learn more are A Typed Foundation for Directional Logic Programming(PDF) and Acceptors as Values: Functional Programming in Classical Linear Logic(PDF) by Uday Reddy, and Frank Pfenning’s lecture notes on linear logic.
